# Typescript pass mapped element to Function onclick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I am at the beginning stage of a Typescript application, and as a proof of concept I wish to simply alert the ID of each item on a button click.  How can I add item.ID to the onclick Alert function below?

```
<table style="background-color:#FFFFFF;width:100px;">
  {resolvedValue.map((item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>
      {item.id}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="javascript:alert('Adding {item.id} ');">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

Update following answer:

```
 <table style="background-color:#FFFFFF;width:100px;">
  {resolvedValue.map((item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>
      {item.id}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={() => alert('Adding')}>Add</button>

      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use React's `onClick` function. See https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-driscoll-mx8dy

```
<table style={{ "background-color": "#FFFFFF", "width": "100px" }}>
  {resolvedValue.map((item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>
      {item.id}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={() => alert('Adding' + item.id)}>Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

Comment: This does not produce an onclick alert when compiled.  I even tried removing the item.id ... posting updated code now

Comment: It works for me. I created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-driscoll-mx8dy